# How to stop %20 from being converted to a whitespace

Tags: php, forms, http-post

I have a little problem with %20 in a html form. I want the value of the input field to be exactly what was typed in. But when someone types %20 it is being converted to a space. It's just a simple HTML form which is being submitted to a PHP backend.

My form

```
<form action="postURL" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"accept-charset="utf-8">
   <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="255"  />
</form>
```

Any thought on it? thanks ahead

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the code you are using ?

Probably an encoding type error on the form you have submitted. See the below for info on encoding types on forms.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Answer (score 0):

`%20` is URL encoded entities.

You need to use `urldecode()` and for decoding use `urlencode()`